# Libgdx tiled map collision detection

Tags: java, libgdx

I am currently working on a 2d rpg game like final fantasy 1-4. Basically, my tiled map can be loaded and the sprite can walk freely on the map.

How do I handle collisions with tiled map?

I have created three separate tile layers. "Background Layer", "Collision Layer", "Overhead Layer" and I am not sure if this is useful or not..

Edit: I have now created an object layer for collisions with rectangles over the areas I wanted the sprite to collide.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This is my current code

```
MapObjects collisionObjects = (GameAssets.mainTiledMap).getLayers().get("CollisionLayer").getObjects();
int tileWidth = 16;
int tileHeight = 16;

for (int i = 0; i < collisionObjects.getCount(); i++) {
    RectangleMapObject obj = (RectangleMapObject) collisionObjects.get(i);
    Rectangle rect = obj.getRectangle();

    rect.set(GamePlayer.x, GamePlayer.y, 16,16);

    Rectangle rectobject = obj.getRectangle();
        rectobject.x /= tileWidth;
        rectobject.y /= tileHeight;
        rectobject.width /= tileWidth;
        rectobject.height /= tileHeight;

    if(rect.overlaps(rectobject)) {
        GamePlayer.ableToMove = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The Super Kaolio example from the source tree has some simple collission detection that you might be able to grok. It helped me greatly to understand. Basically you are checking if your rectangles overlap. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/superkoalio/SuperKoalio.java

Comment: @HinesBourne I have actually tried to follow the example before, but I still dont quite understand the collision part. Right now, the problem is that I have created a box right outside the character instead of the specific rectangles within the object layer of the tiled map.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't recommend using rectangles. Instead, what I did in my own game is:

1. In Tiled, assignate your wall tiles as blocked. To do so, just add a property called block to each individual tile.
2. In the code, when you process the player movement, write something like this pseudo code:

   ```
   try {
       cell = collisionLayer.getCell((int) (x / collisionLayer.getTileWidth()), (int) (y / collisionLayer.getTileHeight()));
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

       if (cell.getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked")) {
       blocked = true;
       }
   ```

where x and y are the position of the cell you want to check. And then if blocked = true, do not move the player. If blocked = false, move the player.

I might have been unclear in this answer, if I was, please don't hesitate to send me a message or check [this awesome tutorial by dermetfan](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0qmqSBhOtqYRjzWtUCWylb).

Comment: Hi, I have actually created three tiled layers `Background Collision Overhead` and to be honest, the reason I wanted to use the object layer is because I used a full image as my tileset instead of separate tiles. so if I used the above method, it will take forever for me to set every single tile properties. (I used 8px tiles)..

Comment: @user2875021 in my snipet, you can use whatever layer you like as your collision layer. Another thing you might what to do is create a invisible layer, which will not be render to scan if the player can go to that tile or not.

Answer (score 2):

In my game i have a 2D int array `walls[][]`, where i store the information about the Tiles. For me 0 is no wall, so i can go throught. All other numbers repressent some special walltypes, wtih which i have to handle collisions. To detect if a collision happens i do something like this:

```
if (yMov > 0) {
    int leftX = (int)(position.x - width/2);    // The leftmost point of the Object.
    int rightX = (int)(position.x + width/2);   // The rightmost point of the Object.
    int newMaxY = (int)((position.y * yMov * currentSpeed * delta) + height/2);
    if (walls[leftX][newMaxY] != 0 || walls[rightX][newMaxY] != 0)
         // Collision in positive y-Direction.
```

Notes:

1. This is presolve, so detect collision first and then move. For this you have to store the result of the collision detection somewhere.
2. The Tiles, in which the character is, are defined by the `Integer` presentation of their `position.x` and `position.y`.
3. `yMov` describes the percntual value of the movement in y-Direction. So if you go 45° to the right, up you have `yMov = 0.5`, `xMov = 0.5`. Left up would be `yMov = 0.5`, `xMov = -0.5`.
4. Use this example code block up there and copy it 3 times, for `yMov < 0`, `xMov > 0`, `xMov < 0`.
5. The position in this example is the middle of the object. If in your case it is the left lower corner you just need to add full height for up-movement, full width for right-movement and no height/ width for the other movements.

**EDIT:** I try to explain it better: You have a `Sprite` defined by his center point:`position.x`,`position.y` and his size: `size.x`, `size.y` (width and height).
Now think about the case, you run to the right. In this case you can never collide with a tile at your left side. Also if you are moving to the right you can not collide with tiles above or under you. So there is only 1 Tile to check: The Tile to your right. Also you can only collide with the Tile to your right, if the right part of your sprite (`position.x + size / 2`) moves far enought.
In case you are moving in between 2 tiles in y direction you have to check the Tile at your `newX` postition and your `upperY` (position.y + size.y / 2) and `lowerY` (position.y - size.y / 2).

To give you a picture of what i am using: [Collision detection](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-tutorial-part-4-collision-detection/). Look at the 3rd picture, with this description:

> The above image gives us 2 candidate cells (tiles) to check if the objects in those cells collide with Bob.

This collision there is for platformers, where you have a gravity, so you have to check the Tile under you cause of that. In top down games this is not the case.
I am not using exactly this method, but the picture shows, what i am doing.

If you have any other questions feel free to ask.

Comment: to be honest I think this is a very complicated way of doing it because I cannot get my head around any of those code above. If I am using my original version above, I have basically created a rectangle right outside my sprite, which means that it is overlapping itself instead of the rectangle object I created on the tile map.

Comment: I try to explain: The Sprite has a `position.x`, `position.y`, defining his central point. Now if you are moving to the right, you can only collide with tiles on your right. So check only for those tiles. For this you only need to add `xMovement` to your `position.x` to get the new position. Tiles are defined by x and y coordinates. So you need to find the y coordinate of your character. It is possible, that your character is in between 2 tiles right? So you need to check, if the tile at the `newX` and `upperY` is empty and the tile at `newX`, `lowerY` is empty. This is what i am doing.

Comment: that is much more clearer as it gives me a better picture of how it works. I will try to understand the article better and implement it if possible. if not, maybe i will switch back trying to use object layer by checking other examples.

Comment: Just a suggestion: If you know another, faster solution don't use the `overlaps` method. If you have to use `overlaps`, cause other methods don't really work for you, first test if the `collisionObject` is near to your `Sprite`. This test would be faster and will sort out 90% of the objects. How to do this `near test`: Store a `float distance`, which stores the distance an object can travel in 1 render loop (use the max possible distance). Then test: `(my.x - collisionObj.x)² + (my.y - collisionObj.y)² < distance²`. If this is the case you can chekc for collision, if not the object is not near

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a method that handles the movement phase, if so the way that I have done it in the past is that after the movement direction is registered run a check against your rectangular collision layer, if the position is to cross over one of the boundaries then return back/run a method for however you want to handle it ie player dies, or players position does not change.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more please? because currently if I use the object layer and test it with  `if (Intersector.overlaps(rectangle, rectangle)` I am not sure how to create the rectangle that can used for representing the sprite/ texture region.

Comment: Ok the way that I would do it is to decide how large your sprite will be and create a rectangle of that size, then anchor the rectangle to your sprites location. Then use the area of sprite hit box, and check to see if that area will intersect with any of the collision layers.

Alternatively you could check all four corners to see if one of them intersected the collision layer, that would work for a tile based game, but would take a bit more processing power to run an if statement for all four corners individually, instead of just checking the total area once.

Comment: if I have a lot of rectangles on the map, do I have to make `Rectangle rect = new Rectangle()` and `rect.set(x, y, width, height)`for collision detection?